# Build a chart on a hidden element with jqPlot

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, canvas, jqplot

I have a page which uses jQuery UI tabs.  When the page loads, I kick off a setTimeout that makes an ajax request every 100ms to get the HTML for each tab's content.  Part of this HTML is a `<div>` for a jqPlot chart and the script to generate it.

The issue I have is that it seems the jqPlot script doesn't like that the elements on tabs 2 .. n are hidden when it tries to build the charts.  The chart on the first tab appears fine, but the charts on all the other tabs never get constructed.

I was able to do a workaround by waiting to call `$.jqplot` on the `show` event for each tab, but then the charts are not getting built until the tab is shown so the user experiences a small delay while the JS builds the chart.

Is there a way to get jqPlot to build these charts when the tabs are hidden?

Comment: Just found `hiddenPlotsInTabs.html` in the documentation included in the download, but didn't see this online. Basically, they suggest the same thing I was doing in my workaround, wait until the tab is shown to call the jqplot method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. Place a matte div over the tab area to hide it (position absolute, z-index 9999)
2. Render all charts
3. After charts have been fully rendered, then run jquery-ui tabs (hiding all but one of the rendered charts)
4. Remove the matte revealing the tabs

---

1. Produce a div with zero height and width and overflow hidden
2. Within that div put very large divs one for each tab
3. Render your charts in those hidden divs
4. Meanwhile produce your jquery ui tabs
5. Move rendered charts into the tabs

---

1. Put an iframe in each tab, and render the charts on separate html pages
2. This way each iframe will execute whether visible or not, and the jquery-ui tabs can switch been charts rendered completely async

---

1. use transforms to move your html off stage left
2. render the charts first
3. after charts are fully rendered, then run jquery-ui tabs (hiding all but one of the rendered charts)
4. move the element back by removing the transform

---

1. Use node.js to generate the jqplot output on the serverside
2. include the output in your page
3. run jquery tabs

Comment: These are great ideas.  I'll try some out.  Thanks!

Comment: I actually wound up sticking with my workaround and accepting the short delay, since that was the suggested approach from the plugin developers.